# Shorten Video By Removing Quiet Audio Sections with Video

Tags: video-editor, editing, audio, automation

What tools are available to take a video and remove out the silent sections found *with its corresponding video track*, where the criteria is that the audio goes below a certain threshold?

---

I can do this by hand by cropping a video. This is done by visually identifying the silent sections in the video via the audio view which are then subsequently highlighted and cut from the video with an automatic join of the video.

But doing that by hand is time consuming..is there a tool or a feature within `Movie Studio Platinum` or `Camtasia` or other software which will remove silent video sections?

---

In a sense this is speeding up the video by removing quiet pauses (with the associated video portion in that cut timeline) as a the person is not talking.  That is my ultimate goal.

Comment: Hello. You write "this is speeding up the video by removing quiet pauses". If you cut the quiet audio parts and the corresponding video footage, you are "speeding it up" simply because you are shortening the length of your clip -- you are cutting out portions of video and audio footage. If you are only cutting out audio portions of your clip, while leaving the video intact, you are not going to "speed up the video". So which is it: are you removing audio and video, or just audio?

Comment: To be clear, it is to remove the audio and associated video during that time slice. I will update the post.